# Interrupt method with other Button using Python and Tkinter

Tags: python, tkinter

I'm still learning how to use Python and Tkinter.

What I want to do is whenever I clicked on a button while a script is running, it'll be able to interrupt the current script that is running. As of now, it does not allow me to click on other button while it's running.

```
    def openPrePlanWindow(self):
        """
        open the flip window and initial all the button and text
        """

        panel = Toplevel(self.root)
        panel.geometry("350x250+300+300")
        panel.wm_title("Gesture Recognition")

        self.btn_end = tki.Button(
            panel, text="End/Emergency", relief="raised", command=self.emergency)
        self.btn_end.pack(side="bottom", fill="both",
                            expand="yes", padx=10, pady=5)

        self.btn_resume = tki.Button(
            panel, text="Resume Pre Plan", relief="raised", command=self.resumeDrone)
        self.btn_resume.pack(side="bottom", fill="both",
                             expand="yes", padx=10, pady=5)

        self.btn_pause = tki.Button(
            panel, text="Pause/Takeover", relief="raised", command=self.interruptDrone)
        self.btn_pause.pack(side="bottom", fill="both",
                            expand="yes", padx=10, pady=5)

        self.btn_start = tki.Button(
            panel, text="Start", relief="raised", command=self.startPreplanRoute)
        self.btn_start.pack(side="bottom", fill="both",
                            expand="yes", padx=10, pady=5)
```

Comment: If your looking to freeze the gui then use `time.sleep(100)` it will freeze the GUI for 100 seconds

Comment: Not really about freezing the GUI. I just want to interrupt or call other method in a sense where there already another script running as currently the GUI won't allow me to press any other button when it runs a script. @CoolCloud

Comment: Then try disabling other buttons.

Comment: If the script is a time-consuming task, better run it in a thread so it won't block the application.